# DuplicateDictionary - A dictionary-like class which allows duplicates

Tags: c#, hash-map

Since I couldn't find any good answers I made my own class called `DuplicateDictionary` for personal usage. I would like some tips to improve it.

```
public class DuplicateDictionary<TKey, TValue>: List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public DuplicateDictionary()
    {

    }

    public DuplicateDictionary(List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> list)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in list)
        {
            this.Add(kvp);
        }
    }

    public DuplicateDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in dictionary)
        {
            this.Add(kvp);
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey index]
    {
        get
        {
            this.ContainsKey(index);
            return this[index];
        }
        set
        {
            this[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in this)
            if(kvp.Key.Equals(key)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

This class is useful for log things. I use it to log a calculator's past functions and numbers, and once equals is pressed, adds all the past numbers with the functions.

Comment: I think you should provide an example on how some1 is supposed to use this class. How are you going to access duplicate values? If you can't then why store them? Also your indexer looks *really* fishy.

Comment: Refer to the edit

Answer (score 15):

Such a data structure already exists, and is called [`ILookup<TKey, TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534291(v=vs.100).aspx). It can be created using the [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.100).aspx) extension.

> The `ToLookup<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)` method returns a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>`, a one-to-many dictionary that maps keys to collections of values. A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` differs from a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which performs a one-to-one mapping of keys to single values.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create("a", 1),
    Tuple.Create("a", 2),
    Tuple.Create("a", 3),
    Tuple.Create("b", 4),
    Tuple.Create("c", 5)
};

var lookup = list.ToLookup(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);

foreach(var kv in lookup)
{
    Console.Write(kv.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(" - " + string.Join(", ", kv));
}

// prints
// a - 1, 2, 3
// b - 4
// c - 5
```

As Vince pointed out, your `DuplicateDictionary` will suffer from slow access. `Lookup` won't.

Answer (score 12):

First I second what [Vince Panuccio](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/30786/vince-panuccio) stated in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102028/29371)

> I don't think this class should have a reason to exist. A key is just that, a key. If you have duplicate keys and duplicate values what you're essentially after is a grouping or a dictionary or with a set or list as its value.

---

**Bug alert**

This will break with an `StackOverflowException`

> ```
> public TValue this[TKey index]
> {
>     get
>     {
>         this.ContainsKey(index);
>         return this[index];
>     }
>     set
>     {
>         this[index] = value;
>     }
> }
> ```

by calling `this.ContainsKey()` which again refers to the `Item` (`this[TKey]`) property  and if we would omit this call, it would just break again with a `StackOverflowException` based on the `return this[index];` which is reffering the property getter itself again.

Setting aside this **big bug**, an argument named `index` usually indicates some kind of numerical type. So a better parameter name would be in this case just `key`.

---

The ctor

> ```
> public DuplicateDictionary(List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> list)
> {
>     foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in list)
>     {
>         this.Add(kvp);
>     }
> }
> ```

could be easily improved by using the `AddRange()` method of the `List<T>` like so

```
public DuplicateDictionary(List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> list)
{
    this.AddRange(list);
}
```

but that isn't really needed in this way because you also have a ctor which takes an `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as a parameter. I suggest to replace both ctors by a different one which only takes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` like so

```
public DuplicateDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> items)
{
    this.AddRange(items);
}
```

which can be called using a `Dictionary` and a `List`.

This looks good but we can still do better by using the ctor of the `List` instead like so

```
public DuplicateDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> items)
    : base(items)
{  }
```

Comment: What does base do? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: Thats the calling of the ctor of the inherited class

Answer (score 7):

It might help if you explain the problem you are trying to solve first, but I'll have a crack at this.

I don't think this class should have a reason to exist. A key is just that, a key. If you have duplicate keys and duplicate values what you're essentially after is a grouping or a dictionary with a set or list as its value.

What you have is a list of `KeyValuePairs` which is not the same as a `Dictionary` :-)

Dictionaries benefit from having unique keys by giving you fast lookups, I'm not sure what benefit you gain by having a `DuplicateDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have some kind of a multi value single key dictionary. So I suggest to use for example a `List<>` to hold the values.

Here's an example:

```
public class DuplicateDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public new IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            List<TValue> values;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out values))
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
            }

            return values.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, v));
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var _value in value.Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
            {
                Add(key, _value);
            }
        }
    }



    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        List<TValue> values;
        if (!TryGetValue(key, out values))
        {
            values = new List<TValue>();
            Add(key, values);
        }
        values.Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in ((Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>)this))
        {
            foreach (var value in item.Value)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(item.Key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dupDic = new DuplicateDictionary<string, string>();

    dupDic.Add("abc", "123");
    dupDic.Add("abc", "456");
    dupDic.Add("xyz", "789");
    dupDic.Add("xyz", "098");
    dupDic.Add("xyz", "290");

    foreach (var kvp in dupDic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key = \"{0}\" Value = \"{1}\"", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can List of KeyValuePair to store duplicates

Example :

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listKeyValPair= new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue= new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY1", "VALUE1");

listKeyValPair.Add(keyValue);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "_Every answer must make at least one **insightful observation** about the code in the question._" Please explain why your suggestion would be an improvement.